# Algebra equations and coding in C

Tags: c, linear-algebra

I'm a beginner with C language, so for a school mini project I need to solve this problem:

Consider a set of streets in the center of a city, with only one direction and intersecting. Assume that there are sensors to detect the number of vehicles entering and leaving the city center, represented in the figure by the quantities. Determine, if possible, the number of vehicles between each of the four intersections. It is intended to develop an application that allows entering the data of the intersections of the city, namely:

- number of streets (a maximum number of streets can be assumed by the application);
- the number of vehicles entering and leaving the city center.

The program should calculate the number of vehicles between each intersection, using the resolution of a system of N equations, where N is the number of intersections.

The development process must involve the subjects taught from the basic introduction of the C language to arrays.

[Image: City Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knU89.png)

So basically, I have no idea how if this is the right way to solve this.
First of all I ignored the part that the user can input the number of streets, because I think it will complicate even more. I'm just working with the 4 streets shown in the example in the image.
So I searched online to see if there was the resolution of this problem, and I found something, I tried to do it from that, but without the values used in there, because in my problem the user is the one who inputs the values in the streets.
I based myself on this: [Resolution for the same problem with different values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuxUg.png) +
[Image of that problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKWLr.jpg)

I don't know if the equations used in that problem was for that example only, and not for unknown values. In that example the x4 was already known, it was 160. But for me x1, x2, x3 and x4 are unknown, the x values are supposed to be calculated from the user inputs. And then by solving the equation we get the x's.

I don't know how to solve that without the x4 value, so I just wrote for the user to input a value to x4. Then the other x’s can be calculated.

Is this even the right way to solve this problem?

My teacher said this is basically just algebra. I'm new at this, so I don't intend to do this completely right, I just want something basic to work. But I have no idea how to “write” algebra in code. Also there might be some errors in the code, cause I had to translate it, but without translation for me the code is working 100%, it doesn't show any error.

My code:

```
int input[3];
int output[3];
int total[3];

int i;

int cars_input;
int cars_output;

int x1, x2, x3, x4;


for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{           
    printf("\nEnter the number of cars entering the street [%d] of the city: ", i); 
    scanf("%d", &input[i]);     
    
    printf("Enter the number of cars leaving the street [%d] of the city: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &output[i]);
    
    
    if(input[i] < 0 || ouput[i] < 0) 
    {
    printf("\nNegative values cannot be entered.");
    return 0;
    }
    
}


cars_input = input[0] + input[1] + input[2] + input[3];

cars_output = output[0] + output[1] + output[2] + output[3];

printf("\n%d cars enter and %d cars leave the city", cars_input, cars_output);


total[0] = output[3] - input[0];
total[1] = output[0] - input[1];
total[2] = output[1] - input[2];
total[3] = output[2] - input[3];
                                
// Not necessary, just wrote this to see if it was working
printf("\n\nTotal 0 %d, Total 1 %d, Total 2 %d, ", total[0], total[1], total[2], total[3]);

printf("\n\nEnter the number of cars between intersection C and D: ");
scanf("%d", &x4);


x3 = x4 + total[2];

x2 = x3 + total[1];

x1 = x2 + total[0];


printf("\nx1 = %d \tx2 = %d \tx3 = %d \tx4 = %d", x1, x2, x3, x4);


return 0;
```

Comment: I have not read all the description you gave , but programming point of view, you have declared `int input[3];` but in the loop you are trying to store 4 values `for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)`

Comment: Consider an intersection, say A now the number of vehicles entering the intersection, 450 + x_1, must be equal to the number of vehicles exiting the intersection, 610 + x_3, or  in equation form, 610 + x_3 = 450 + x_1.  With rearrangement we get x_1 + 0*x_2 - x_3 + 0*x_4 = 160.  Doing the same with the other three intersections will yield a total of four equations in four unknowns.  There are many ways to solve such a system - Cramer's rule, Gaussian elimination, etc.  See if this helps with the problem

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea how to “write” algebra in code.

You start by writing it down using mathematical notation. What you want here is to manually solve a system of four equations, with symbols (e.g. letters) substituted in place of any fixed numbers that may vary based on user input. Simple example:

- Equations - x are unknowns, a and b are user inputs or fixed numbers

  ```
  a11*x1 + a12*x2 = b1   (eq1)
  a21*x1 + a22*x2 = b2   (eq2)
  ```
- Solving manually for `x1`: take eq2 multiplied by `-a12/a22` and add to eq1:

  ```
  (a11 - a21*a12/a22)*x1 + (a12 - a22*a12/a22)*x2 = b1 - (a12/a22)*b2
  (a11 - a21*a12/a22)*x1 + (a12-a12)*x2 = b1 - (a12/a22)*b2
  x1 = (b1 - (a12/a22)*b2) / (a11 - a21*a12/a22)
  ```
- Solving manually for `x2`: first reorder eq2 to isolate x2, then substitute x1 into it (once you got a numerical value for it)

  ```
  x2 = b2/a22 - a21/a22*x1
  ```

The expression for `x1` and `x2` is basically valid C code, you just need to add variable declarations and populate the `a` and `b` coefficients from user input.

Code that up, just to get some feel for how it might look.

Then look up Gaussian elimination, which is a more mechanized process of solving a system of N equations. Start by writing it down on e.g. a 4x4 system in your own handwriting to get a feel for the process. Then code up the necessary variable declarations for the arrays of coefficients and of the unknown, and then write the loop (or loops) that will execute the steps of the gaussian elimination on those arrays. And then you'll be done.